# Using libfmt with a legacy API

Tags: c++20, fmt

I want to measure performance of vsnprintf against a modern formatting library, specifically libfmt, on top of a legacy C API. It is not possible to use C++ directly at the caller. How can I do this?

```
const char *fmt, ...
```

The arguments we get passed is not unexpectedly a format string followed by a variadic argument list. The output needs to be zero-terminated. If this is not possible to get the maximum performance out of, I would have to instantiate a version of every format string manually. Right now I'm trying to avoid this.

The destination is a buffer with a provided maximum length. We cannot use heap for anything. There is no heap.

Comment: "*It is not possible to use C++ directly at the caller.*" Um, what does that mean? If you're programming in C++, using a C++ library, then how can you *not* be able to use C++?

Comment: The legacy API that makes the calls pass the arguments as specified in the code block. That is, it's a C variadic argument list. C is the caller. I updated the question body to reflect that.

Comment: Are you saying that there is C code calling a function with a C variadic interface, and the implementation of that code is C++? And you want to process the C variadic inputs in some way? Well... how will you know what type the arguments are? `fmt`'s format strings, if I recall correctly, do not contain typing information.

Comment: I know the types by checking if I know the format string, and if I don't I can call vsnprintf as a fallback. The goal is to see if FMT_COMPILE will give performance benefits even with this clunky setup, as the legacy code is and will continue to be in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very fundamental distinction between how fmt works compared to printf. Namely, fmt's formatting strings contain no type information.

`fmt` is based on C++ variadic templates. Type information is expected to be transmitted as is typical of C++: through *compile-time* mechanisms. As such, `fmt`'s format strings don't need to repeat the type information that all of the formatting functions inherently contain. This strong typing allows `fmt` to allow type-based extensibility features.

C variadics erase all type information. Without type information stored in the string, there's no way to recover the type information that `fmt` *needs* to do its job.

The libfmt library contains a `dynamic_format_arg_store` type (this is not part of C++20, but I think you might be able to built it). However, even this requires that you *know* the type at the point where you're storing the arguments. Since C variadics already erased the type, you're out-of-luck.

The fundamental assumptions of `fmt` as a library make it incompatible with C variadics.

Comment: I agree with you this is a hard problem - however I have started "switch casing" on the string literals passed to the printing functions, which lets me switch on the format strings. With that I do have the types know ahead of time. There is a fallback to vsnprintf for unhandled format strings.

Answer (score 2):

{fmt} is a C++ library and it doesn't provide the C API, so you'll need to use a C++ compiler or write your own C wrapper. You could use [`dynamic_format_arg_store`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv2N3fmt24dynamic_format_arg_storeE) to build the argument list in your wrapper but it will be less efficient than using the C++ API directly.